# Trigger Javascript with URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this snippet to fade content into a div when a specific link is clicked....

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#section1, #section2, #section3').addClass('js');
        $('#content-container a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#' + rel).fadeIn().siblings('div').fadeOut();
        });
        var link = document.URL.split('#')[1];
        if (link) {
            var el = $('#' + link);
            if (el) el.click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to load the specified content using a URL instead of clicking?  So I can link to www.mydomain.com/mypage.php#section2 or something similar?

### UPDATE

Here is a jsfiddle of the simplified code http://jsfiddle.net/k6RhR/

Comment: What will be the values of `link`?

Comment: You mean when people open the URL with the # already attached? It looks like you're already doing that by doing `el.click()`. I.e. Faking a user click.

Comment: Are you looking for this [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange)?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = link` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try This

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mouseover demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .invisible
        {
            display: none;
        }
        .lorem
        {
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getContent();
        });
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
            getContent();
        });

        function getContent() {
            var url = window.location.toString();
            var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#'));
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 2000);
            $(hash).fadeIn();
            $(hash).siblings("div").fadeOut();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lorem">
        <div id="section1" class="invisible">
            Content 1
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Content 1 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section2" class="invisible">
            Content 2
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Content 2 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section3" class="invisible">
            Content 3
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Content 3 content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section4" class="invisible">
            Content 4
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Content 4 content
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="links">
        <a href="#section1" rel="section1" id="section1">Section 1</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#section2" rel="section2" id="section2">Section 2</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#section3" rel="section3" id="section3">Section 3</a>
        <br />
        <a href="#section4" rel="section4" id="section3">Section 4</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you are looking for. On load the page will look for the #section to show the content. On click of the anchor the hash link will be changed and the hash change function will load in the required content.

If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate this into what I already have.  I have updated the original post with a jsfiddle to better demonstrate

Comment: to confirm your requirement .. you want the div "section1" to fade in when the url is invoked as "URL"#section1 ?

Comment: Have made some modification .. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Seems to be a lot simpler than the way I was doing it previously as well

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash=="#section2") {
    // Do stuff that are meant to happen when this hash is present.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to specify the portion of the page like:

```
$( "#container" ).load( "/mypage.php #section2" );
```